# Async/Await strange behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

```
const [enviar,setEnviar]=useState(true);

    const redirectUser=()=>{
        
        const fetchMenu= async ()=>{
            const response= await fetch('/api/Menu/ListarMenuPorIdUsuario',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    IdUsuario:Number(userSession.user.id)
                }),
                headers: {
                  'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                }
              });
              const data= await response.json();
              setEnviar(!data.Data.some(e=>e.Nombre==="Administrar"));
              console.log(enviar,userSession.user.id);
        }

        if(userSession.user.id!==-1){
            fetchMenu();
            
             
        }else{
            navigate('/Account');
        }
    }
```

I've got the function redirectUser() that is called by pressing a button. The operation !data.Data.some(...) results in false. But for some reason when I press the button it outputs true to the console, the next time I try pressing the button it finally outputs false. Does it have to do with some async/await behaviour I am unaware of?

Comment: The initial state of `enviar`  is set to `true` so the first time the DOM is rendered, your `enviar` is set to  `true` thus why you see `true` first. It won't be until a re-render that the state of `enviar` gets updated then you see `false` thus why you need two clicks to see an updated state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was happening because of how useState works, it holds a value per render, so until the rerender happens you can only access to the value before setState is called. In this case there's no rerender until the event is finished so `enviar` holds the value of true.
The way I solved it is by using a useEffect hook with a `fetched` value in its dependencies and an if statement so it only runs once the data is fetched and the rerender has happened.

```
const [enviar,setEnviar]=useState(true);
const [fetched,setFetched]=useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{
    if(fetched){
        console.log(enviar);
    }
    return ()=>{setFetched(false)};
},[fetched]);

const redirectUser=()=>{

    if(userSession.user.id!==-1){
        fetchMenu();
         
    }else{
        navigate('/Account');
    }
}

const fetchMenu= async ()=>{
    try{
        const response= await fetch('/api/Menu/ListarMenuPorIdUsuario',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                IdUsuario:Number(userSession.user.id)
            }),
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            }
          });
          const data= await response.json();
          setEnviar(!data.Data.some(e=>e.Nombre==="Administrar"));
          setFetched(true);
    }catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }
    
}
```